# how to copy information from one sector to a pen drive with the help of c program?

Tags: c

and if i want to access a hard disk which is containing some data and i want to copy that from one sector to another , then is it possible ?

Comment: What OS? What you are asking to do is impossible in standard C, so you have to use your OS API.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533219/how-do-i-access-a-raw-sector-of-disk-in-xp-with-a-c-program/3533720#3533720

Answer (score 1):

A sector is meaningless without a file system.  Surely both your pen drive and the hard disk have one that your operating system supports?  Then there's little point to not use fopen() and friends.